# Flight Control Weight limitations

Tags: weight-and-balance

Does anybody know any limitations of flight control weights? 
For instance elevators must have same weight? What is the acceptabld difference/limits and what would be the reason of overweighting? (Paint, bushings, repairs etc). 
Please consider A320s and B737s for giving example

Answer (score 1):

Flight control mass balance weights are used primarily to prevent things like flutter. Most airline manufacturers are able to perform analysis of their designs to determine the exact weight to introduce, and where to place it. The rest use static balancing. [This article from the Experimental Aircraft Association](https://www.eaa.org/en/eaa/aircraft-building/building-your-aircraft/while-youre-building/building-articles/control-systems/how-to-mass-balance-control-surfaces) is not an airliner example, but it provides a good explanation of the why and how of flight control balancing.

Comment: this is not what I am looking for.  aircraft maintenance manual of an A319 doesn't specify why/wether or not RH elevator should be heavier than LH elevator.

Comment: Probably because that information is only useful to depot maintenance facilities that perform work requiring r/r of flight control surfaces/